# The caravan is coming and my rock crafts are scattered on the floor!

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After a massive influx of migrants one season, I set up a stonecrafting sweatshop to churn out hundreds of rock toys and mugs. But it looks like I screwed up my stockpile settings and/or didn't have enough bins to hold the mountain of goods. So the items exist, but not in convenient finished goods bins.

The elven caravan is now here, and my dwarves aren't fast enough to carry each item to the trade depot individually. After some frantic carpentering, I think I have enough bins to hold everything.

How do I order my dwarves to put the rock toys into the empty bins?

Comment: Eh, elves have always had garbage offers... better haul the nearest items to the depot now, and do the binning at leisure, for the summer, when the humans show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you <kbd>q</kbd>uery the craft stockpile, you can increase the number of "Reserved bins". This will ensure they are used for crafts.

Answer (score 5):

At this point it's probably too late. It will take almost as much time to pack up the items as it will to get it to the depot. Get what you can to the depot, and worry about efficient storage later. Start w/ stuff that is in bins, and a page or so of crafts that are closest to the depot. Once that is hauled over, start selecting more. You probably won't get everything to the depot in time for this caravan, but you should be able to get enough to do some trading, especially if you temporarily make all of your craft-dwarves haulers.